# unit test using JUnit

Tags: java, ant, junit, environment-variables, netbeans-7

I'm using NetBeans 7.4, and this is my first example with JUnit so i have this WARNING in the output console:

```
WARNING: multiple versions of ant detected in path for junit 
         jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/NetBeans%207.4/extide/ant/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/Project.class
     and jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/glassfish-4.0/glassfish/modules/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/Project.class
Testsuite: utilitaire.TraitementFichierTest
copyFile
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0,069 sec

------------- Standard Output ---------------
copyFile
------------- ---------------- ---------------
Testcase: testCopyFile(utilitaire.TraitementFichierTest):   FAILED
expected:<false> but was:<true>
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<false> but was:<true>
    at utilitaire.TraitementFichierTest.testCopyFile(TraitementFichierTest.java:52)


Test utilitaire.TraitementFichierTest FAILED
```

Comment: I guess this isn't a JUnit issue. It's really the *`multiple versions of ant detected`* that matter.

Comment: but it cosed when i run the Junit test

Comment: Yes, there seems something wrong in your setup or configuration.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a test failure, multiple junit versions(from Netbeans bundled & galssfish) is just a warning, doesn't cause a failure

```
    testCopyFile(utilitaire.TraitementFichierTest):   FAILED
expected:<false> but was:<true>
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<false> but was:<true>
    at utilitaire.TraitementFichierTest.testCopyFile(TraitementFichierTest.java:52)
```

Check TraitementFichierTest.java line 52, you assert for a false, but gets a true, that is the cause for failure.

Comment: it caused by  fail("The test case is a prototype."); function